# Significance Levels(Region of rejection) vs P value comparison

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, inference

Correct me if I am wrong,
The region of rejection is we picked up a significant level then use that to calculate rejection region while P value is the conditional probability of alternative hypothesis $Ha$ on $Ho$ is true then we compare with significant level?

Is significant level a conditional probability of Reject Ho on Ho is true?

Comment: $p$-value has nothing to do with $H_0$ being true. Check https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-is-the-meaning-of-p-values-and-t-values-in-statistical-tests for a start or this recent thread https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/347653/is-the-sum-of-p-value-and-specificity-1

Comment: Thanks. According to the link you refer, $P$($Samplemean$ ≥ 5ft 9inches|$Truevalue$=5ft7inches).Which the true value is $Ho$ is true which $u$ is population mean? I thought it is same as my understanding?

Comment: $P(X|H_0) \ne P(H_0|X)$

Comment: Thanks Tim. If I edit my question as this way, does it make more sense?

Comment: re-read/digest the link, my understanding is: region of rejection is by positioning $Z$ test result in the confidence interval, we can see whether the null hypothesis is rejected or not. Same conclusion can be obtained from $P$ value test. After calculate $P$ value from alternativehy pothesis $Ha$ on Null hypothesis $Ho$, if value is greater than significant level then we don't reject $Ho$, but if value is smaller, we reject it.

Comment: Can I say the region of rejection test is using Z value. It just simply reject the result without showing the strength of significance? This is why we introduce P value

Comment: what do you mean  by strength of significance ?  Are you  making a reference  to  any thing  different from  level of significance ?

Answer (score 0):

the region of rejection test is using Z value. It just simply reject the result without showing the strength of significance? This is why we introduce P value

Comment: To me, the  rejection region shows  the proportion of  area  under  normal curve  that  accommodates  values  of Z  beyond that  of normal distribution.

Comment: It  shows  the area  occupied by  outliers  (Z  values more than  the  expected  Z  under  the  assumption of   (say) alpha  =  .05 . The  probability or  alpha level  for  a  given distribution  of observed  scores  is  usuailly  calculated by simulation. If  the calculated probability is  less than or equal to  say,  assumed alpha (.05), we say that  the effect-size is statistically significant at  .05 .